# Problem 1.K.(e) of Kelley

Tags: general-topology, real-numbers

I am working on problem K from the first chapter of Kelley and I can not solve part (e) of this problem. I know that every open subspace of a separable space is separable, but this is not enough. Maybe we can use (d) to solve it, I guess. Could you please help me?

Edit: Now I have got an idea. We shall find a dense subset of $A$. Fix a $N\in\mathbb{N}$, then we are able to divide $\mathbb{R}$ into countably some parts, namely
$$ \mathbb{R}=\bigcup _{k=-\infty}^\infty\left[\frac{k}{N},\frac{k+1}{N}\right).$$
For every $k$, if $\left[\frac{k}{N},\frac{k+1}{N}\right)\cap A\neq\varnothing$, then pick an element from it, and put $A_N$ as the set of such elements. Now since $A_N$ is countable, $\cup_{N=1}^\infty A_N=A_0$ is also countable. By (d), we know that $A$ only has got countably some accumulation points in itself. Denote the derived set of $A$ by $A'$, we shall prove that $A_0\cup \left(A\setminus A'\right)$ is dense in $A$. For an accumulation point $a\in A$, if $a\in A_0$, then there is nothing to prove; if not, then since $a$ is an accumulation point of $A$, for any neighbourhood $\left[a,b\right)$ of $a$, there are always some $c\in \left(a,b\right)\cap A$. Choose $N$ large enough such that $\frac{1}{N}<\min \left(c-a,b-c\right)$, then there will be some $k_N\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $c\in\left[\frac{k_N}{N},\frac{k_N+1}{N}\right)$, then since $\left[\frac{k_N}{N},\frac{k_N+1}{N}\right)\cap A\neq \varnothing$ and $\left[\frac{k_N}{N},\frac{k_N+1}{N}\right)\subset \left[a,b\right)$, there must be some points in $\left[\frac{k_N}{N},\frac{k_N+1}{N}\right)\cap A_0$, hence in $\left[a,b\right)\cap A_0$.
[image: Kelley 1.K]

Answer (score 1):

The closure of your set $A_0$ contains all point that are accumulation points of $A$ from the right; add the points from 1(d) to that and there is your countable dense set.